# Name error depending on debug mode of python flask application

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

When running the flask app 'app.py' without debug mode, everything runs fine:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hey there"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Server startign:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When running the Flask app in debug mode
`app.run(debug=True)`  I'll get "No module named app" error and the server won't start:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
No module named app
```

I have noticed that when starting the script in vsCode without debug mode (ctrl+f5) or press the button 'Run Python File' everything works fine.
When I start debugging (f5) in vsCode the 'No module named app' occurs and after the failed server start I jump back to the parent folder (app.py is in /folder/app/app.py - after server start failed I am in the terminal in the '/folder' rather then '/folder/app' like before starting the script.

Does anyone got an idea where the problem is? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved by adding a launch.json file to the workspace and adding either an absolute to your app.py file:

```json
"cwd":"path/to/folder/"
```

or a relative path to the directory of the executed script:

```json
"cwd":"${fileDirname}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If your workspace have multiple project then this "cwd" (current working directory) parameter helps to identify which app file to pick under the workspace.